# Speeding up Newton's Method for finding nth root

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx

Let me predicate this question with a statement; This code works as intended but it is slow very very slow for what it is. Is there a way to make it the newton method converge faster or a way to set a __m256 var equal to a single float without messing with the float arrays and such?

```
__m256 nthRoot(__m256 a, int root){

#define aligned __declspec(align(16)) float

// uses the calculation
// n_x+1 = (1/root)*(root * x + a / pow(x,root))


//initial numbers
aligned r[8];
aligned iN[8];
aligned mN[8];

//Function I made to fill arrays
/*
template<class T>
void FillArray(T a[],T b)
{
int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(T);
for(int i = 0; i < n; a[i++] = b);
}*/

//fills the arrays
FillArray(iN,(1.0f/(float)root));
FillArray(mN,(float)(root-1));
FillArray(r,(float)root);

//loads the arrays into the sse componenets
__m256 R = _mm256_load_ps(r);
__m256 Ni = _mm256_load_ps(iN);
__m256 Nm = _mm256_load_ps(mN);

    //sets initaial guess to 1 / (a * root)
__m256 x = _mm256_rcp_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(R,a));

for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i ++){
    __m256 tmpx = x;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < root -2 ; k++){
        tmpx = _mm256_mul_ps(x,tmpx);
    }
    //f over f'
    __m256 tar = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(tmpx)); 
    //fmac with Ni*X+tar
    tar = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Nm,x,tar);
    //Multipled by Ni
    x = _mm256_mul_ps(Ni,tar);
}
return x;
}
```

Edit #1

```
__m256 SSEnthRoot(__m256 a, int root){

__m256 R = _mm256_set1_ps((float)root);
__m256 Ni = _mm256_set1_ps((1.0f)/((float)root));
__m256 Nm = _mm256_set1_ps((float)(root -1));

__m256 x = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(R));

for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i ++){
    __m256 tmpx = x;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < root -2 ; k++){
        tmpx = _mm256_mul_ps(x,tmpx);
    }
    //f over f'
    __m256 tar = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(tmpx)); 
    //mult nm x then add tar because my compiler stoped thinking that fmadd is a valid instruction
    tar = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(Nm,x),tar);
    //Multiplied by the inverse of power
    x = _mm256_mul_ps(Ni,tar);
}

return x;
}
```

Any tips or pointers(not the memory kind) to make it the newton method converge faster would be appreciated.

Edit #2 removed on _mm256_set1_ps() function call with _mm256_rcp_ps() because I had already loaded the reciprocal of what I had needed into R

```
__m256 SSEnthRoot(__m256 a, int root){
__m256 R = _mm256_set1_ps((float)root);
__m256 Ni = _mm256_rcp_ps(R);
__m256 Nm = _mm256_set1_ps((float)(root -1));

__m256 x = _mm256_mul_ps(a,Ni);
for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i ++){
    __m256 tmpx = x;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < root -2 ; k++)
        tmpx = _mm256_mul_ps(x,tmpx);
    //f over f'
    __m256 tar = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(tmpx)); 
    //fmac with Ni*X+tar
            //my compiler believes in fmac again
    tar = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Nm,x,tar);
    //Multiplied by the inverse of power
    x = _mm256_mul_ps(Ni,tar);
}
return x;
}
```

Edit #3

```
__m256 SSEnthRoot(__m256 a, int root){
__m256 Ni = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f/(float)root);
__m256 Nm = _mm256_set1_ps((float)(root -1));
__m256 x = _mm256_mul_ps(a,Ni);
for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i ++){
    __m256 tmpx = x;
    for(int k = 0 ; k < root -2 ; k++)
        tmpx = _mm256_mul_ps(x,tmpx);
    __m256 tar = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(tmpx)); 
    tar = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Nm,x,tar);
    x = _mm256_mul_ps(Ni,tar);
}
return x;
}
```

Comment: How much speed improvement was there when you switched to using `_mm256_set1_ps` and how much faster does it need to be ?

Comment: It only speed it up by 86 milliseconds for 1000000 of each function. Time for the improved function = 2816. Time for the old function 2900 mill. I fixed the for loop iteration number the SSEnthRoot function to be the same as the unimproved one.

Comment: That's the current speed ? And what are you aiming for ? The numbers seem very wrong though, as that's 3 µs per function call, which is way too high (unless `root` is a large number ?).

Comment: I'm finding the 29th root.

Comment: OK - 3 µs still seems high though - you are compiling with all optimisations enabled I hope, e.g. `-O3` ?

Comment: Yup -Ox full optimizations and whole program optimization

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  I'll see if I can come up with a solution over the next few days.  One quick comment, with AVX you should use 32 bit alignment.  If you compile & run your code with Visual studio in 32 bit mode it crashes. Using #define aligned __declspec(align(32)) float fixed this.  Probably in 64-bit code it defaults to 32-bit alignment.

Comment: I mean 32 byte alignment not 32 bit.

Comment: Your pow function is inefficient.  You use 27 multiplications to calculate x^28.  This can be done in only 6 multiplications.  I added a function to my answer that does this more efficiently with AVX.

Comment: I improved your function further.  It now finds the nth root within some tolerance rather than just doing 20 iterations.  It could be much faster if the convergence happens in less than 20 iterations.

Comment: In case you're interested, I think I found a faster function which also iterates until it finds the most accurate result possible for float http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110227/flt-epsilon-for-a-nth-root-finder-with-sse-avx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pow` function is inefficient.

```
for(int k = 0 ; k < root -2 ; k++)
        tmpx = _mm256_mul_ps(x,tmpx);
```

In your example you're taking the 29th root.  You need  `pow(x, 29-1) = x^28`.  Currently you use 27 multiplications for that but it's possible to do that in only six multiplications.

```
x^28 = (x^4)*(x^8)*(x^16)
x^4 = y -> 2 multiplications
x^8 = y*y = z -> 1 multiplication
x^16 = z^2 = w-> 1 multiplications
y*z*w -> 2 multiplications
6 multiplications in total
```

Here is **an improved version of you code which is about twice as fast on my system**.  It uses a new `pow_avx_fast` function which I created which does x^n for 8 floats at once using AVX.  It does e.g. x^28 in 6 multiplications instead of 27.   **Please see further into my answer.  I found a version which finds the result within some tolerance `xacc`.  This could be much faster if the convergence happens quick.**

```
inline __m256 pow_avx_fast(__m256 x, const int n) {
    //n must be greater than zero
    if(n%2 == 0) {
        return pow_avx_fast(_mm256_mul_ps(x, x), n/2);
    }
    else {
        if(n>1) return _mm256_mul_ps(x,pow_avx_fast(_mm256_mul_ps(x, x), (n-1)/2));
        return x;
    }
}

inline __m256 SSEnthRoot_fast(__m256 a, int root) {
    // n_x+1 = (1/root)*((root-1) * x + a / pow(x,root-1))
    __m256 R = _mm256_set1_ps((float)root);
    __m256 Ni = _mm256_rcp_ps(R);
    __m256 Nm = _mm256_set1_ps((float)(root -1));

    __m256 x = _mm256_mul_ps(a,Ni);
    for(int i = 0; i < 20 ; i ++) {
        __m256 tmpx = pow_avx_fast(x, root-1);
        //f over f'
        __m256 tar = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(tmpx)); 
        //fmac with Ni*X+tar
        //tar = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Nm,x,tar);
        tar = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(Nm,x),tar);
        //Multiplied by the inverse of power
        x = _mm256_mul_ps(Ni,tar);
    }
    return x;
}
```

For more information how to write an efficient `pow` function see these links http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring

Also, your initial guess might not be so good.  Here is scalar code to find the nth root based on your method (but using the math `pow` function which is probably faster than yours).  It takes about 50 iterations to solve the 4th root of 16 (which is 2).  For the 20 iterations you use it returns over 4000 which is no where close to 2.0.  So you will need to adjust your method to do enough iterations to ensure a reasonable answer within some tolerance.

```
float fx(float a, int n, float x) {
    return 1.0f/n * ((n-1)*x + a/pow(x, n-1));
}
float scalar_nthRoot_v2(float a, int root) {
    //sets initaial guess to 1 / (a * root)
    float x = 1.0f/(a*root);
    printf("x0 %f\n", x);
    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        x = fx(a, root, x);
        printf("x %f\n", x);
    }
    return x;
}
```

I got the formula for Newtons method from here.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm

Here is a version of your function which gives the result within a certain tolerance `xacc` or quits if no convergence after `nmax` iterations.  This function could be much faster than your method if the convergence happens in less than 20 iterations.  It requires that all eight floats converge at once.  In other words, if seven converge and one does not then the other seven have to wait for the one that does not converge.  That's the problem with SIMD (on the GPU as well) but in general it's still faster than doing it without SIMD.

```
int get_mask(const __m256 dx, const float xacc) {
    __m256i mask = _mm256_castps_si256(_mm256_cmp_ps(dx, _mm256_set1_ps(xacc), _CMP_GT_OQ));
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm256_castsi256_si128(mask)) + _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm256_extractf128_si256(mask,1));
}

inline __m256 SSEnthRoot_fast_xacc(const __m256 a, const int root, const int nmax, float xacc) {
    // n_x+1 = (1/root)*(root * x + a / pow(x,root))
    __m256 R = _mm256_set1_ps((float)root);
    __m256 Ni = _mm256_rcp_ps(R);
    //__m256 Ni = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f/root);
    __m256 Nm = _mm256_set1_ps((float)(root -1));

    __m256 x = _mm256_mul_ps(a,Ni);

    for(int i = 0; i <nmax ; i ++) {
        __m256 tmpx = pow_avx_fast(x, root-1);
        __m256 tar = _mm256_mul_ps(a,_mm256_rcp_ps(tmpx)); 
        //tar = _mm256_fmadd_ps(Nm,x,tar);
        tar = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(Nm,x),tar);
        tmpx = _mm256_mul_ps(Ni,tar);
        __m256 dx = _mm256_sub_ps(tmpx,x);
        dx = _mm256_max_ps(_mm256_sub_ps(_mm256_setzero_ps(), dx), dx); //fabs(dx)
        int cnt = get_mask(dx, xacc);
        if(cnt == 0) return x;
        x = tmpx;
    }
    return x; //at least one value out of eight did not converge by nmax.
}
```

Here is a more general version of the pow function for avx which works for n<=0 as well.

```
__m256 pow_avx(__m256 x, const int n) {
    if(n<0) {
        return pow_avx(_mm256_rcp_ps(x), -n);
    }
    else if(n == 0) { 
        return _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f);
    }
    else if(n == 1) {
        return x;
    }
    else if(n%2 ==0) {
        return pow_avx(_mm256_mul_ps(x, x), n/2);
    }
    else {
        return _mm256_mul_ps(x,pow_avx(_mm256_mul_ps(x, x), (n-1)/2));
    }
}
```

Some other suggestions

You can use a SIMD math library which finds the nth root.  [SIMD math libraries for SSE and AVX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723995/simd-math-libraries-for-sse-and-avx)

For Intel you can use SVML which is expensive and closed source (Intel's OpenCL driver uses SVML so with that you can get it for free).  For AMD you can use LIBM which is free but closed source.  There are several open source SIMD math libraries such as http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/avx_mathfun/ and https://bitbucket.org/eschnett/vecmathlib/wiki/Home

Answer (score 2):

To set all elements of an `__m256` vector to a single value:

```
__m256 v = _mm256_set1_ps(1.0f);
```

or in your specific case:

```
__m256 R =  _mm256_set1_ps((float)root);
__m256 Ni = _mm256_set1_ps((1.0f/(float)root));
__m256 Nm = _mm256_set1_ps((float)(root-1));
```

Obviously you can get rid of the `FillArray` stuff once you've made this change.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be doing this in the log domain.

```
pow(a,1/root) == exp( log(x) /root)
```

Julien Pommier has a [sse_mathfun.h](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/sse_mathfun.h) that has SSE,SSE2 log and exp functions, but I cannot say I've used those in particular. The techniques may be extensible to avx.