# AVX log intrinsics (_mm256_log_ps) missing in g++-4.8?

Tags: c++, g++, intrinsics, avx

I am trying to utilise some AVX intrinsics in my code and have run into a brick wall with the logarithm intrinsics.

Using the Intel Intrinsics Guide v3.0.1 for Linux, I see the intrinsic `_mm256_log_ps(__m256)` listed as being part of "immintrin.h" and also supported on my current arch.

However trying to compile this simple test case fails with "error: ‘_mm256_log_ps’ was not declared in this scope"

The example was compiled with `g++-4.8 -march=native -mavx test.cpp`

```
#include <immintrin.h>
int main()
{
        __m256 i;
        _mm256_log_ps(i);
}
```

Am I missing something fundamental here?  Are certain intrinsics not supported by g++ and only available in icc?

SOLVED: This instruction is not a true intrinsic but instead implemented as part of the Intel SVML for ICC.

Comment: Can you see that function, or any similarly-named functions in `immintrin.h`?

Comment: I don't believe the math functions are officially part of the SSE/AVX intrinsic set. Those are probably MKL extensions that's included with the Intel Compiler.

Comment: @nneonneo No, and in none of the related gcc headers.

Comment: @Mysticial I was worried that might be the case.

Comment: @Mystical They are actually SVML functions. SVML (Short Vector Math Library) is a tiny library supplied with Intel compiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As indicated in the comments to your question, that intrinsic doesn't map to an actual AVX instruction; it is an Intel extension to the intrinsic set. The implementation likely uses many underlying instructions, as a logarithm isn't a trivial operation.

If you'd like to use a non-Intel compiler but want a fast logarithm implementation, you might check out [this open-source implementation of `sin()`, `cos()`, `exp()`, and `log()` functions using AVX](http://software-lisc.fbk.eu/avx_mathfun/). They are based on an earlier [SSE2 version](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/) of the same functions.

Comment: [simd-math-libraries-for-sse-and-avx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723995/simd-math-libraries-for-sse-and-avx) lists some other options besides SVML which can be used.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted my implementation of `_mm256_log_pd(__m256d)` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898937/1915854 . With some effort you should be able to extend it to 8 packed `float`s instead of 4 `double`s, though you need to revise the bit manipulations. And some parts are easies because you don't need to repack odd-/even-numbered 32-bit components of `__m256i` into `__m128i`.